# Telegram Bot Send PDF File via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm Trying To Send a File With ID But does not Work For Some Files, I'm Using 
**node-telegram-bot-api** module.

```
bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, "BQADBAADFAADAllAUeZn_0YHHRjNAg");     //ok
bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, "http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf");//ok

bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, "BQADBAADAgAD8jBJUZjgAdwyxsADAg")  //  Not Ok
```

I Have This Error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: 400 {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: Wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Telegram reference:** [Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files)
`Sending by file_id`,
file_id is unique for each individual bot and can't be transferred from one bot to another.

**Do these steps:**
1: Send a PDF file to your bot.
2: Get that file id via forwarding to raw bot (@RawDataBot) or ...
3: send via [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) Module.
Example:

```
bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, "BQADBAADAgAD8jBJUZjgAdwyxsADAg")
```